# Good Library for Creating E-mail Templates with Merge Ability

Tags: c#, asp.net, components, libraries

I'm looking for a really good library/component/framework for creating e-mail templates for my web application.

We send out a number of e-mails on a regular basis:

- Activate Your Account
- Welcome
- Thanks for Your Order
- Etc.

I'd like to give the non-technical administrators of my web app a way to:

- See the current e-mail template (HTML, WYSIWYG)
- Make some minor modifications to copy, colors, etc.
- Preview, Test, Save, and "deploy" a new version of the e-mail template.

The tool needs to support "merge" fields.  For an example, see [MailChimp.com](http://www.mailchimp.com/resources/merge/).  They allow users to create e-mail templates and then specify any number of fields like this:
*|FIELD1|*
*|FIELD2|*

Then, when sending an e-mail, the developer passes-in the appropriate info for each field.

```
An example:

Hi *|FIRSTNAME|*,

Thanks for signing up.  You rule!

Best regards,
MyWebSite.com
```

Does anyone know of a tool like this that can plug into my ASP.NET / C# web app?  I assume someone out their wrote a library/component/something that I can license.

Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

Try this one. It's free and open source:

http://mailsystem.codeplex.com/

It includes some classes specifically designed for mail merging

What's nice is that you can use its mail merging capabilities and still use system.net.mail for sending the email to avoid breaking your code.

Answer (score 0):

Here is another option.

http://ntemplates.codeplex.com/