# How to Send automatic emails like newsletter

Tags: c#-3.0, windows

I see some question closed by administrator with similar question.
I will try to explain in detail the solution I'm looking for:

First I'm trying to develop a windows console application.

**Sending frequency:** monday to friday

**How many users:** from 5 to 20

**Format of data:** 
A table where rows are countries and columns different types of products and the cells represent the sale of that country-product

**Limitation:** 
Service users prefer not to use a pdf or excel or attachment of any type should be a html format possible to show in the body of mail

Currently I am creating the report almost artisan with something like:

```
.....
var myStringBuilder = new StringBuilder("<!DOCTYPE HTML PUBLIC \"-//W3C//DTD HTML 4.0 Transitional//EN\">");
myStringBuilder.Append("<html><head><meta http-equiv=\"Content-Type\" content=\"text/html; charset=iso-8859-1\">");
myStringBuilder.Append("</head><body>");
myStringBuilder.AppendLine();
myStringBuilder.Append("<table style=\"font-family: Calibri; text-align: right; font-size: x-small;\">");
myStringBuilder.AppendLine();
var header = new StringBuilder("<tr><th>a</th><th>CATEG1</th><th>CATEG2</th><th>CATEG3</th><th>CATEG4</th><th>TOTAL</th></tr>");
var line = new StringBuilder("<tr><td>a</td><td>b</td><td>c</td><td>z</td><td>e</td><td>f</td></tr>");
foreach (var a in _actuals)
        {
            line.Replace("a", a.CountryName);
            if(a.Segment.ToLowerInvariant().Equals("categ1")) {
               line.Replace("b", "[" + string.Format("{0:0,#}", a.LsvLcFact / 1000) + "]"); }
            else if (a.Segment.ToLowerInvariant().Equals("categ2")) {
               line.Replace("c", "[" + string.Format("{0:0,#}", a.LsvLcFact / 1000) + "]"); }
            else if (a.Segment.ToLowerInvariant().Equals("categ3")) {
               line.Replace("z", "[" + string.Format("{0:0,#}", a.LsvLcFact / 1000) + "]"); } 
            else {
               line.Replace("e", "[" + string.Format("{0:0,#}", a.LsvLcFact / 1000) + "]"); }
          }
 .....
```

And in the class to send mail something like:

```
    public void SendResumen(string subject ,StringBuilder content)
    {
        var oMsg = new MailMessage...;
        ... add users
        oMsg.Subject = subject;
        var mimeType = new ContentType("text/html");
        var alternate = AlternateView.CreateAlternateViewFromString(content.ToString(), mimeType);
        oMsg.AlternateViews.Add(alternate);
        oMsg.IsBodyHtml = true;
        var cli = Client();
        cli.Send(oMsg);
    }
```

Finally, I hope you understand what I'm doing and the question is:
Is there a tool I can use to not generate as crafted the message body?

Comment: I think you're looking for mail merge functionality. Take a look at http://stackoverflow.com/q/3463809/56778

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I Accept the suggest from @Jim-Mischel

Answer (score 0):

I have a VB application that can send out messages that have an HTML payload, and it doesn't use the AlternateView functionality.

```
Dim mail As New MailMessage(fromUser.Email, toUser.Email)
mail.Subject = subject
mail.IsBodyHtml = True
mail.Body = message
```

While it would be nice to use the AlternateView functionality for those email clients that can't read the HTML payload, your code can't really use it because you're only supplying an HTML message.  If you did manage to get the AlternateView functionality to work here, any client that couldn't read HTML would see the HTML markup instead of just simple message text. For this to truly work, I think you would need to provide both a text and HTML email message body.